# Distance between icons

Tags: icons, panel, gnome-panel, system-tray, top

Anybody knows how to change distance between icons in top panel ubuntu 18.04? I need to do it smaller

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try installing this Gnome Extension: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/355/status-area-horizontal-spacing/